# Add roman numbers in the begining of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add roman numbers to the chapters before the introduction in my table of contents. I have tries multiple way but none work. Which code should I use?

Comment: Can you please add a short example of what you mean? Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so we don't have to repeat anything you might have done?

Comment: As in `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}`?  Note that the table of contents uses text recorded in the aux file.  it does not reformat them.

Comment: I now managed to add the roman numbers in my TOC but in my List of Figures the figures are named for example 1-1 I want it to be 1.1 how do I do this? I´m using article class and \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}